# how to set the value we are returned from the attribute of other elements onclick function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

hello everyone anyone can help me 
I have a problem I'm created this function to create a button and  get t attribute vaue from the main button and set this value to onclick event the buttons will be created but don't work

```
<button id="d" t="Demo();" onclick="CreateAndSetEvents();">click me</button>
<script>
function CreateAndSetEvents(){
var eval;
    var x=document.getElementById('d');
    if(x.hasAttribute("t")){
        eval=x.getAttribute('t');
        var el=document.createElement("input");
        el.setAttribute("type","button");
        el.setAttribute("value","created");
        el.onclick=function(){ eval}//now the value of eval is Demo function but why don't work ?! 
        document.body.appendChild(el);
    }
}
function Demo(){
alert("hello from demo ');
}
</script>
```

Comment: How is that related to jQuery? Don't spam tag, we don't appreciate it

Comment: What you expect the onclick to do? The handler function contains only an expression which doesn't do anything. If you have something looking like a function call in `eval`, notice, that it's just a string.

Comment: I want get t value as a function instead of string or other way convert string value to Finction object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are number of issues with your code.

First

```
alert("hello from demo ');
```

should be

```
alert("hello from demo ");
```

You need to match your opening quotes to your closing quotes

Second eval is a reserved keyword in javascript, so you really shouldn't be using it as a variable name.

I would strongly recommend you start using JSLint to clean up your code before running it, it will catch syntax errors like this

Third, event handlers registered in html should not be followed by semicolons.

Fourth, and most relevant to your needs, when you get the attribute t from your button d, you are not getting the function Demo, you are getting the string "Demo()" you cannot just put that string in a function and execute it.

Javascript does contain a builtin function for evaluating strings as code called eval. However, using it is a REALLY BAD IDEA. What if somebody passes a string to your eval that posts malicious data to your server, or asks for sensitive         information? Eval is a huge security threat.
If you did wan't to use eval, you would use it like this:

```
<button id="d" t="Demo()" onclick="CreateAndSetEvents()">click me</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function CreateAndSetEvents() {
    var f;
    var x = document.getElementById('d');
    if (x.hasAttribute("t")) {
        f = x.getAttribute('t');
        alert(f);
        var el = document.createElement("input");
        el.setAttribute("type", "button");
        el.setAttribute("value", "created");
        el.onclick = function() {
            eval(f);
            };
         //now the value of eval is Demo function but why don't work ?! 
        document.body.appendChild(el);
    }
}

function Demo() {
    alert("hello from demo");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Guy I'm forgeted eval function now my problem was fixed Thank you a lot of <3

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to avoid the eval function, you could do it like this:

```
el.onclick = function() {
    window[f].call();
};
```

Then you have to use only the name of the function in your attribute with-out parentheses.

I think it's better than using eval because it's limited to functions that are available at the window object.

```js
var CreateAndSetEvents = function() {
    var f;
    var x = document.getElementById('d');
    if (x.hasAttribute("t")) {
        f = x.getAttribute('t');
        //alert(f);
        var el = document.createElement("input");
        el.setAttribute("type", "button");
        el.setAttribute("value", "created");
        el.onclick = function() {
            //eval(f);
            window[f].call();
            };
         //now the value of eval is Demo function but why don't work ?! 
        document.body.appendChild(el);
    }
};

function Demo() {
    alert("hello from demo");
}
```

```html
<button id="d" t="Demo" onclick="CreateAndSetEvents()">click me</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```